# How to get event.action for .net core lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

Event object in aws lambda has several useful properties to use like event.action and event.headers etc. In node.js lambda this is easily available in method's signature.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
```

How can I get the same thing in .net core lambda which just have user's passed data and context object in it?

```
  public string FunctionHandler(object userData, ILambdaContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different paradigmes, so you can't get the same API for two different environments.

Node.js version (non-async handler) has no return type, so there is only one way to return something from you hander - invoke a callback.

.NET version has a return type for handler, so you can simply return something from your handler instead of calling callback.

According to the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html the first parameter of your handler is the input to the handler, which can be event data (published by an event source) or custom input that you provide such as a string or any custom data object.